# C# reporting tool that compiles into the executable

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, crystal-reports, reportviewer

I have a Winforms C# application that uses .Net framework 3.5. The application currently makes use of `Crystal Reports` for various reporting functions. This application is typically being installed as a networked application; in other words, the application is installed on a server and then launched from the various workstations via a shortcut. To run correctly though, the Crystal Reports runtime needs to be installed on **every** workstation and this is a dependency that I would like to eliminate. My goal is to be able to install the application on the server and then as long as .Net framework 3.5 is installed on the client, the application, including reporting, will launch and execute correctly.

So does anyone know if it is possible to compile Crystal Reports into the executable so that the dependency on the runtime is eliminated, or, failing that, know of an alternative to Crystal Reports that can does not depend on a runtime being installed on the client?

UPDATE:

I am currently looking at using a `Visual Studio 2008` `ReportViewer` control as an alternative to `Crystal Reports`. I have never used this control before (or 'Reporting Services' for that matter), but from what I have read it is possible to setup this control to run using a built-in reporting engine (a so-called 'local mode'). If this is indeed the case, then I should be able to define the reports in `Visual Studio 2008` and compile them into the application executable so that neither `Reporting Services` on the server nor a reporting runtime on the client need be installed.

Comment: Have you looked into creating MSI...?

Comment: At the moment I have an MSI that installs the application on the server. I have a separate MSI that installs the dependencies for the application on the clients. This MSI for the client installs .Net 3.5 if it is not found and installs Crystal Reports runtime. My goal is to have a situation where so as long as the client machine is running Windows 7, the client MSI installation is not needed.

Comment: can you add some conditional statements to the install to check the OS ..?

Comment: What I am trying to get across here is that I want to have a situation where the MSI installation (which is currently necessary to install Crystal Reports) is not necessary at all _for Windows 7 clients_. If my customers want to have Windows XP clients, they would then have to run the MSI to install .Net 3.5 framework. But if they stick to Windows 7 clients then no installation is necessary because .Net framework 3.5 is pre-installed and the application has no other dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Reports does always need to install standalone, I've been dealing with that for a while now, mine is a ClickOnce Application, actually I'm making some Reports using Report Viewer but I should warn you IT NEEDS TO INSTALL TOO on client machines so you will need Admin Privilegies on new installs.

What I 'm doin now is changing to a pure dll generation reporting solution as Telerik or DevExpress, right now I'm using DevExpress one.

Disclaimer: I do NOT work for either company.

Regards,